# Nginx and Heroku. Serving Static Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, git, heroku, nginx

Goal:

Going to https://secret-sands-1568.herokuapp.com/myFile.html will display the content of `client/myFile.html` sent by Nginx.

---

From what I understand, Heroku dynos are normally used for Nodejs/Ruby/other apps but they can be converted to anything by modifying the buildrack.

- I copied the content of https://github.com/theoephraim/nginx-buildpack.
- I added a folder named `tmp` with a file `app-initialized`.
- I added a folder named `client` with a file `myFile.html`.

In `config/nginx.conf.erb`, I changed `location /` by

```
    location / {
        root   client;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

- I created a file `Procfile` with content: `web: bin/start-nginx`.
- I entered `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack.git`.
- I entered `git init` `heroku create` `git push heroku master` `heroku ps:scale web=1`.

---

Yet, when I go https://secret-sands-1568.herokuapp.com/myFile.html, there's nothing. Heroku logs says:

```
2015-05-19T07:13:32.990254+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:33.995458+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:34.998228+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:36.000823+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:37.005955+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:38.008548+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:39.011184+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:40.013788+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:41.016516+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:42.019372+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:43.023551+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:44.029985+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:45.035183+00:00 app[web.1]: buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization
2015-05-19T07:13:45.910618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-05-19T07:13:45.910618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-05-19T07:13:46.732519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-19T07:13:46.718745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-05-19T07:17:12.890713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=6d15e849-ce45-41bc-9bad-60d9eb0454ef fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-19T07:17:13.039723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=7aeecc36-05b5-4799-bf0a-6ba97b2a6190 fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-19T07:17:18.350029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/myFile" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=cb77356f-ddf3-4795-b56d-fa9cde5d134a fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-19T07:17:18.471762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=64a89596-b287-4b89-a3ce-ed750e4fb1c1 fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-19T07:17:22.250495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=4ccda4e8-1532-49dc-8658-e67312ef333d fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-19T07:17:22.125124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/myFile.html" host=obscure-caverns-1927.herokuapp.com request_id=33cdee81-2dda-44cb-acf7-2dc5b4156ef2 fwd="24.200.222.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What am I doing wrong? My goal is to have a stand-alone Nginx server that deserve static file.

Comment: `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` indicates that nginx or some other webserver is trying to bind to `$PORT` without luck.. check permissions (port 80 or 443, for example, can only be used by privileged users) and your nginx config and whether there's something already using the port (`netstat tulpne` should do the trick)..

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: For serving static files specifically, you don't need to go through all the effort of this.  There's a buildpack [heroku-community/static](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static) which is hugely more simple than the nginx ones, and the instructions cater to static sites.  And I just got my Angular site working using it.

---

I know this probably won't help the original asker, but it will probably help others who find this.

**Note**: This is only a partial answer.  I'm still looking for more debugs.  But I managed to get mine to go from a Timeout to serving all 404 pages by doing the following.

Also note, I'm not using one from github.  I'm using https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx, added via `heroku buildpacks:add heroku-community/nginx`

Procfile:

```
web: bin/start-nginx-solo
```

This should serve static files instead of trying to route to another listener.

So far, I keep getting nginx errors as follows: `open() "/dist/index.html" failed  (2: No such file or directory)`  (These are from `app[web.1]`).  The build was successful, but it just can't locate any of the files.  Still working on that, but at least it doesn't crash due to boot timeouts anymore.