# Problem deploying nginx on heroku in front of server on Go

Tags: go, nginx, heroku, deployment

I want to deploy to heroku nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my Go application.
I made a config file for nginx, but its samples presented here https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx do not give an understanding of which port to specify in the proxy_pass directive to redirect to my application. These examples use unix socket listening instead of http.

```
  upstream app_server {
server unix: /tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout = 0;
}
```

But my application is running over http.

In addition, heroku uses random ports, which the application must retrieve from the PORT environment variable. However, now I have set this variable in the config for nginx. What port should my application run on now? If you specify your own port, this will not work, since heroku will say that the port is already busy.

I am completely discouraged by the difficulty of deploying a simple environment for my heroku application. None of the heroku instructions give a comprehensive understanding of how this can be done.

Please guide me on the right path.

P.S. For a couple of days of searching for an answer, I found only a lot of questions similar to mine and not a single answer.

---

Update.
I did as in this post [Springboot application with nginx as proxy deploy on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855434/springboot-application-with-nginx-as-proxy-deploy-on-heroku)
But the author did not explain what she set in the APP_PORT variable. I set it to 3001 and got the same thing as here:
[Nginx and Heroku. Serving Static Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319200/nginx-and-heroku-serving-static-files)